# Google Pinyin for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there a Google Pinyin app for iPhone? Current pinyin on iPhone is really bad.

Comment: Per the flag we received: Not a very useful question and a lazy one at that. A search through the App Store would answer this. Even google itself could answer this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. Google has only released the Pinyin app with support for Windows. A Mac OS X beta did come out last year, but it hasn't been released publicly, and as far as I know, there's no support for mobile devices.

[Source](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/)